# Fortran Syntax in Geany

Tags: 12.04, geany, fortran

I use Geany 1.22 in Ubuntu 12.04, but it isn't highlighting Fortran syntax. What is the solution?

Comment: if you highlight one variable and would like to see all variables with the same name highlighted, how does it work in Geany?

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the file with a ".f" or ".f90" extension in the filename.

Or, in Geany, go to:

Document > Set Filetype > Programming Languages > Fortran (the version you want)